# Parsing an XML file from Map Editor Tiled?

Tags: xml, 2d, d

I'm setting up the framework for my new project and I decided to use the Tiled Map Editor. I've setup a very basic map, just for the purpose of understanding how the map data is saved in XML format but I'm having trouble understanding what the important parts are.

I've opened up the .tmx file in notepad just to take a look around and nothing really stands out to me that says what tile types are in the map.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" width="25" height="19" 
  tilewidth="32" tileheight="32"> 
  <tileset firstgid="1" name="Test" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
   <image source="../TileSet/TestTileSet.png" width="320" height="320"/> 
  </tileset>
  <layer name="Tile Layer 1" width="25" height="19"> 
 <data encoding="base64" Compression="zlib"> 
 eJzjYmBgYKQh5qGx+aN4FI/iUTyKRzElmJfG5nMDMQCDZQIG 
</data> </layer> </map>
```

This is a copy paste of the notepad text. I can see information like the orientation, width, height, tileset source, it's width/height etc.

From this I don't see where I get the tile information so I can render.

What exactly is this "eJzjYmBgYKQh5qGx+aN4FI/iUTyKRzElmJfG5nMDMQCDZQIG" ?

For reference i'm using the D programming language.

Any help in understand this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It's the sprite data, compressed using the [deflate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) algorithm, and then encoded with [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

```
$ echo 'eJzjYmBgYKQh5qGx+aN4FI/iUTyKRzElmJfG5nMDMQCDZQIG' | base64 -d | perl -MCompress::Zlib -e 'undef $/; print uncompress(<>)' | xxd -c 19
0000000: 0a00 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000 0100 00  ...................
0000013: 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 00  ...................
0000026: 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000 01  ...................
...
```

Comment: Ok, is there anything currently written in D that would help me decompress and decode this?

Comment: Yes, there is `std.base64` and `std.zlib` in the standard library.